# Git clone без дополнительного каталога

Tags: linux, windows, git

Есть *git* репозиторий на *ubuntu*.
Использую *Git Gui* для *Windows*.
Рабочий каталог для проекта `D:/site.ru/www`

После того, как делаю `git clone`, структура рабочего каталога меняется в зависимости от названия репозитория.

Т.е. было `D:/site.ru/www`, стало `D:/site.ru/www/repository_name`

Подскажите, может настройки на сервере или локально нужно выполнить, чтоб `git clone` помещал файлы в папку `www`, не создавая дополнительной?

Comment: чекаутит репозиторий и помещает в папку с названием репо. нужно запустить  'git init' и сказать что-за репо

Comment: Насколько я знаю, после git clone можно опционально указать название будущей папки (или же путь к ней). То есть я к тому, что, по идее, создание папки таким образом можно отменить.

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `git clone`? Зная немного больше, возможно найти иной способ решения проблемы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выполните в папке www:

```
git init .
git remote add origin <repoURL>
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 6):

можно выполнить в **пустом** каталоге (например, `www`):

```
 $ git clone url-хранилища .
```

точка в конце — это именно то, чего вам не хватает.

Comment: Это приведет к ошибке `fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
`

Comment: слово «пустом» я специально выделил жирным шрифтом. вы считаете, что надо ещё дополнительно сделать его крупнее?

Comment: да, вы правы, в пустом такого не будет. Еще крупней не надо)